# deleting 2 or more tables using join in mysql

Tags: mysql, join

Hi every one i have a project which i need to delete 4 tables at the same time using join in mysql
this is my query:

```
DELETE product_tbl, product_rebate, product_terms, product_cashp, product_downpayment 
FROM product_tbl INNER JOIN product_rebate ON product_tbl.Prod_ID = product_rebate.Prod_ID 
 INNER JOIN product_terms ON product_tbl.Prod_ID = product_terms.Prod_ID 
 INNER JOIN product_cashp ON product_tbl.Prod_ID = product_tbl.Prod_ID;
```

it 's not working it gives me an error:  #1109 - Unknown table 'product_tbl' in MULTI DELETE

Comment: last inner join is unwanted remove it and try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
DELETE product_tbl, product_rebate, product_terms, product_cashp, 
       product_downpayment
FROM   product_tbl
       INNER JOIN product_rebate
            ON  product_tbl.Prod_ID = product_rebate.Prod_ID
       INNER JOIN product_terms
            ON  product_tbl.Prod_ID = product_terms.Prod_ID
       INNER JOIN product_cashp
            ON  product_tbl.Prod_ID = product_cashp.Prod_ID;
```

I think you've made mistake here in last inner join,

```
  INNER JOIN product_cashp
            ON  product_tbl.Prod_ID = product_tbl.Prod_ID; -- both side same table?
```

Comment: thanks rajesh i did not notice it now i get it my code is now running smoothly this is what i did : DELETE product_tbl, product_rebate, product_terms, product_cashp, product_downpayment FROM product_tbl 
INNER JOIN product_rebate ON product_tbl.Prod_ID = product_rebate.Prod_ID
INNER JOIN product_terms ON product_tbl.Prod_ID = product_terms.Prod_ID
INNER JOIN product_cashp ON product_tbl.Prod_ID = product_cashp.Prod_ID
INNER JOIN product_downpayment ON product_tbl.Prod_ID = product_downpayment.Prod_ID
WHERE product_tbl.Prod_ID = 3;

Answer (score 0):

MySQL DELETE JOIN with INNER JOIN

```
DELETE T1, T2
FROM T1
INNER JOIN T2 ON T1.key = T2.key
WHERE condition
```

Try this :-

```
DELETE product_tbl, product_rebate, product_terms, product_cashp, 
       product_downpayment
FROM   product_tbl
       INNER JOIN product_rebate
            ON  product_tbl.Prod_ID = product_rebate.Prod_ID
       INNER JOIN product_terms
            ON  product_tbl.Prod_ID = product_terms.Prod_ID
       INNER JOIN product_cashp
            ON  product_tbl.Prod_ID = product_cashp.Prod_ID;
```

Comment: I already posted this answer.Try this example is same as mine. you have not observed this before.

Comment: would it be in the same format if i use it in my update query?